# Pset1 Cash problem: Program prints nothing when run

Tags: c, cs50

This is my code from pset1 Cash problem.
It asks the question and does keep asking until properly answered.
Now it just isn't continuing the rest of the process. The program just stops once answered.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void)
{   
    float money;
    int coins;
    int i;
    do
    {
    //asking customer
        money = get_float("How much change is owed? ");        
    }
    while(money <= 0);
    coins = round(money * 100);
    for (i=0; coins == 0; i++)
    {
        //quarters
        if (coins >= 25)
        {
            coins = coins - 25;
        }
        //dimes
        else if (coins >= 10)
        {
            coins = coins - 10;
        }
        //nickels
        else if (coins >= 5)
        {
            coins = coins - 5;
        }
        //pennies
        else if (coins >= 1)
        {
            coins = coins - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            (printf("%i", i));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Run your program in a debugger. Or add debug print statements. When a program doesn't work that's what should be done to debug it (posting on SO should be a last resort).

Comment: review `coins == 0`

Comment: `for (i=0; coins == 0; i++)` --> `for (i=0; coins != 0; i++)` and move `printf("%i", i)` to be **after** the loop

Comment: `In function 'main':
error: expected declaration or statement at end of input`

Comment: @kaylum thanks for the tip. are there specific programs that you can recommend?

Comment: For debugger you mean? Depends on what system you use. On Linux `gdb` is the standard debugger. Windows I'm less familiar but use Visual Studio occasionally.